# Typescript compilation errors in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular, karma-runner, tsc

So, I have been trying to learn `Angular 2` for some days now ([Github Repo](https://github.com/abhinavmsra/Angular2-jasmine-karma)). For unit testing, I have been trying to configure `Jasmine` and `Karma`. I have been following these projects as a base

1) [Testing Angular 2 with Karma and Jasmine](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2016/01/testing-angular-2-with-karma-and-jasmine/)

2) [seed Angular2 application](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed)

However, for some reasons I am not getting the configurations right. May be due to lack of experience on front end development.

First I got errors with message:

`node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(77,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.`

I found similar issue posted [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7280) 
 and followed the solution as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ericmdantas/angular2-typescript-todo/blob/master/index.ts#L1)

However now I am receiving following errors:

```
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,1): error TS2654: Exported external package typings file cannot contain tripleslash references. Please contact the package author to update the package definition.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(12,6): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(15,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
```

For this error, I didnt find any convincing solution. So, can someone help me out with it?

Thanks in advance.

**Configuration Details:**

1) Package.json

```
{
  "name": "learning",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning Angular 2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc -p src/",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"http-server -c-1 -o -p 8875 .\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "posttest": "node_modules/.bin/remap-istanbul -i coverage/coverage-final.json -o coverage -t html",
    "coverage": "http-server -c-1 -o -p 9875 ./coverage",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.14",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.5.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.25",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings":"^0.7.12"
  }
}
```

2) tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "../dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Same problem here during a webpack build with ts-loader.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in rxjs bet 5. Wait for beta 6 or downgrade to 4 using

```
 npm install rxjs@5.0.0-beta.4 --save.
```

Comment: Reference issues on [angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7919) and [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/1551)

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the definition file in your apps entry point:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7280